# How to get current month record in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Need to get record of current month but query return the wrong result.There is only one record in db.but i get wrong count for the current month

```
$data = UserData::select(
    DB::raw("count(phone) as total")
)
    ->whereMonth('creation_date', Carbon::now()->month)
    ->get();
return view('kpidata', compact('data'));
```

this is result of mysql query
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgYSu.png)

and this is the result i get using laravel query[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuL8h.png)

Comment: can you show your data? and what result you get?

Comment: What is the datatype of column ```creation_date```

Comment: datatype for creation_date is date

Answer (score 7):

"whereMonth" compares only the month number not the year

**Option 1:**

```
UserData:select(DB::raw("count(phone) as total"))
    ->whereBetween('creation_date', 
        [
            Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), 
            Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()
        ])
    ->get();
```

**Option 2:**

```
UserData:select(DB::raw("count(phone) as total"))
    ->whereYear('creation_date', Carbon::now()->year)
    ->whereMonth('creation_date', Carbon::now()->month)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanku but none of the above query is wroking. Still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

Here Item is a modal.

```
$data = Item::select('*')
            ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->get();
   
print_r($data);
```

Comment: i have already tried but it gives the same result

Answer (score 1):

You actually need a full date by using the `whereMonth` and not just the integer equivalent of the month.

```
$data = UserData::whereMonth('creation_date', Carbon::now())->get();

return view('kpidata', compact('data'));
```

Also, if you just want to display the recordcount, you can just do:

```
$data = UserData::whereMonth('creation_date', Carbon::now())->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `whereMonth()` and similar "helper" methods. They are a dreadful habit and lead to unnecessarily inefficient queries. This may not matter when testing on your local machine, but if you are fortunate enough to get your application into the "wild" and it is successful with 1,000s of concurrent users, it may be the difference between success and failure.

Your code -

```
$data = UserData::select(
    DB::raw("count(phone) as total")
)
    ->whereMonth('creation_date', Carbon::now()->month)
    ->get();
```

will result in a query that looks something like -

```
select count(phone) as total
from users
where month(creation_date) = :month
```

Because of the `month()` function wrapped around `creation_date` the server is unable to use any available index on `creation_date`. It is also unnecessarily executing the function for each row. Read more about [Non-SARGable Predicates](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/).

As already suggested by @Heroherm, you should use `whereBetween()` -

```
$data = UserData::selectRaw('count(phone) as total')
    ->whereBetween('creation_date',
        [
            Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'),
            Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d')
        ]
    )
    ->get();
```

which will result in a query that looks something like -

```
select count(phone) as total
from users
where creation_date between :start and :end
```

If this does not work, as previously suggested, please use `->dd()` in place of `->get()` to see what is going on.